# XSL apply-template within external data

Tags: xml, xslt, external, apply-templates

I would like to transform an XML that represents classes and its base classes, with classes that include its own methods and attributes, plus the methods and attributes for its all base classes, as OO inheritance works.

An XML for that could be

```
<classes>

    <class name="A" author="Mr.X" >
        <attribute name="i_" type="integer" visibility="protected" />
        <attribute name="f_" type="float" visibility="private" />
        <attribute name="c_" type="char" visibility="private" />
        <method name="foo" return="integer" visibility="public" >
            <param name="a" type="integer" />
            <param name="b" type="integer" />
        </method>
    </class> 

    <class name="B" author="Mr.Y" >
        <attribute name="s_" type="string" visibility="protected" />
        <method name="bar" visibility="public" />
    </class> 

    <class name="CA" author="Mr.Z" base="A" >
        <attribute name="d_" type="double" visibility="protected" />
    </class>

    <class name="CB" author="Mr.Z" base="B" />

    <class name="DCA" author="Mr.X" base="CA" >
        <attribute name="s_" type="string" visibility="protected" />
    </class>

</classes>
```

that should be transformed into

```
<classes>
  <class name="A" author="Mr.X">
    <attribute name="i_" type="integer" visibility="protected"/>
    <attribute name="f_" type="float" visibility="private"/>
    <attribute name="c_" type="char" visibility="private"/>
    <method name="foo" return="integer" visibility="public">
      <param name="a" type="integer"/>
      <param name="b" type="integer"/>
    </method>
  </class>
  <class name="B" author="Mr.Y">
    <attribute name="s_" type="string" visibility="protected"/>
    <method name="bar" visibility="public"/>
  </class>
  <class name="CA" author="Mr.Z">
    <attribute name="d_" type="double" visibility="protected"/>
    <!--[begin] inherited from class A by Mr.X-->
    <attribute name="i_" type="integer" visibility="protected"/>
    <attribute name="f_" type="float" visibility="private"/>
    <attribute name="c_" type="char" visibility="private"/>
    <method name="foo" return="integer" visibility="public">
      <param name="a" type="integer"/>
      <param name="b" type="integer"/>
    </method>
    <!--[end] inherited from class A-->
  </class>
  <class name="CB" author="Mr.Z">
    <!--[begin] inherited from class B by Mr.Y-->
    <attribute name="s_" type="string" visibility="protected"/>
    <method name="bar" visibility="public"/>
    <!--[end] inherited from class B-->
  </class>
  <class name="DCA" author="Mr.X">
    <attribute name="s_" type="string" visibility="protected"/>
    <!--[begin] inherited from class CA by Mr.Z-->
    <attribute name="d_" type="double" visibility="protected"/>
    <!--[begin] inherited from class A by Mr.X-->
    <attribute name="i_" type="integer" visibility="protected"/>
    <attribute name="f_" type="float" visibility="private"/>
    <attribute name="c_" type="char" visibility="private"/>
    <method name="foo" return="integer" visibility="public">
      <param name="a" type="integer"/>
      <param name="b" type="integer"/>
    </method>
    <!--[end] inherited from class A-->
    <!--[end] inherited from class CA-->
  </class>
</classes>
```

With the help of [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3016153/michael-hor257k), I have the following XSL that works fine if all the classes was defined in the same XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="parent" match="class" use="@name" />

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="class">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name()!='base']|node()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('parent', @base)" mode="inherit"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="class" mode="inherit">
        <xsl:comment>
            <xsl:text>[begin] inherited from class </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            <xsl:text> by </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@author"/>
        </xsl:comment>
        <xsl:copy-of select="attribute | method"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('parent', @base)" mode="inherit"/>
        <xsl:comment>
            <xsl:text>[end] inherited from class </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        </xsl:comment>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or the following transformation that is equivalent but with no keys.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="class">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name()!='base']|node()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//class[@name=current()/@base]" mode="inherit"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="class" mode="inherit">
        <xsl:comment>
            <xsl:text>[begin] inherited from class </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            <xsl:text> by </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@author"/>
        </xsl:comment>
        <xsl:copy-of select="attribute | method"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//class[@name=current()/@base]" mode="inherit"/>
        <xsl:comment>
            <xsl:text>[end] inherited from class </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        </xsl:comment>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now, I would like to handle that these classes can be able to be defined in the main xml or in other XML files, linked with the other file with an import element, that means that the external XML can be used as if it were written in the main XML.

A simplified XML that represents these classes could be

```
<classes>    
    <import file="c2.xml" />

    <class name="XZ" author="Mr.B" base="Z">
        <method name="foo" visibility="public" />
    </class>
</classes>
```

and the content of c2.xml could be

```
<classes>
    <class name="Z" author="Mr.A" >
        <attribute name="i_" type="integer" visibility="protected" />
    </class> 
</classes>
```

and the expected output would be

```
<classes>
  <class name="Z" author="Mr.A">
    <attribute name="i_" type="integer" visibility="protected"/>
  </class>
  <class name="XZ" author="Mr.B">
    <method name="foo" visibility="public"/>
    <!--[begin] inherited from class Z by Mr.A-->
    <attribute name="i_" type="integer" visibility="protected"/>
    <!--[end] inherited from class Z-->
  </class>
</classes>
```

The new XSL is quite similar to the that above one but adding the following pattern, in order to handle the new  elements

```
<xsl:template match="/classes/import">
    <xsl:comment>
        <xsl:text>importing </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@file"/>
        <xsl:text> file</xsl:text>
    </xsl:comment>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@file)/classes/node()" /> 
</xsl:template>
```

So, the XSL will be like the following one when using keys

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="parent" match="class" use="@name" />

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/classes/import">
        <xsl:comment>
            <xsl:text>importing </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@file"/>
            <xsl:text> file</xsl:text>
        </xsl:comment>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@file)/classes/node()" /> 
    </xsl:template>  

    <xsl:template match="class">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name()!='base']|node()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('parent', @base)" mode="inherit"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="class" mode="inherit">
        <xsl:comment>
            <xsl:text>[begin] inherited from class </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            <xsl:text> by </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@author"/>
        </xsl:comment>
        <xsl:copy-of select="attribute | method"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('parent', @base)" mode="inherit"/>
        <xsl:comment>
            <xsl:text>[end] inherited from class </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        </xsl:comment>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or like the following one where no keys are used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/classes/import">
        <xsl:comment>
            <xsl:text>importing </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@file"/>
            <xsl:text> file</xsl:text>
        </xsl:comment>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@file)/classes/node()" /> 
    </xsl:template>  

    <xsl:template match="class">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name()!='base']|node()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//class[@name=current()/@base]" mode="inherit"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="class" mode="inherit">
        <xsl:comment>
            <xsl:text>[begin] inherited from class </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            <xsl:text> by </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@author"/>
        </xsl:comment>
        <xsl:copy-of select="attribute | method"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//class[@name=current()/@base]" mode="inherit"/>
        <xsl:comment>
            <xsl:text>[end] inherited from class </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        </xsl:comment>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The transformation associated with import elements works fine for the classes defined in the external file, but the base class inheritance behavior, does not apply in those classes.

The (wrong) output for the above XSL and the previous XML (the one that includes c2.xml files) is

```
<classes>
  <!--importing c2.xml file-->
  <class name="Z" author="Mr.A">
    <attribute name="i_" type="integer" visibility="protected"/>
  </class>
  <class name="XZ" author="Mr.B">
    <method name="foo" visibility="public"/>
  </class>
</classes>
```

Please note that the XZ class does not include methods and attributes from its base class Z

Be aware that external xml files could include also the import elements

I have tried two different approaches. The first one was to use keys for the classes, including those that were declared in external XML files. I failed with that, because I do not know the external filenames in advance, in order to generate the keys for the classes defined in these external XML files. The second one was to apply the "inherit" mode predicates, but again I failed because I do not know the external filenames in order to apply the template class with inherit mode for all that files.

Any help regarding to how to apply the "inherit" template for the classes from external data, would be really appreciated. Any approach, with or with no keys, are fine for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keys only work within a single document. I'd suggest two approaches:

(a) first combine all the documents into one, then use your current solution.

(b) rather than using keys, build a cross document index in the form of an XSLT 3.0 map. Something like this:

```
<xsl:mode name="index" on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

<xsl:variable name="globalIndex" as="map(xs:string, element(*))">
  <xsl:map>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="index"/>
  </xsl:map>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="class" mode="index">
  <xsl:map-entry key="@name" select="."/>
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="index"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="import" mode="index">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="doc(@file)" mode="index"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and then where you previously used `key('parent', @base)`, you can now use `$globalIndex(@base)`.

(c) This solution won't give you the speed of keys or maps, unless your processor has a smart optimizer (like Saxon-EE) which indexes things automatically; but it only uses XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:variable name="allClasses" as="element(class)*">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="index"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="class" mode="index">
  <xsl:sequence select="."/>
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="index"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="import" mode="index">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="doc(@file)" mode="index"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()" mode="index">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="index"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and then where you previously used `key('parent', @base)`, you can now use `$allClasses[@name=current()/@base]`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply. Without using keys, could be possible to achieve that? Performance is not an issue since the XMLs are not so large, so it may be feasible to use a non-keys approach . If not, I will follow the first approach that you suggest. Thank you again for your time. Regards. Hernan

Comment: You could use a similar approach to create a global variable containing (references to) all the class elements across all documents, and then use a filter expression to find the class containing the one with the required name.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit about the above option?. As far as I know, variables are loaded before applying template patterns, and their values cannot be modified or updated. Therefore, I should know the external XML files in advance, but this is not the case, since the files to look for, are information of the XML itself. What would be the minimum XSL version that I should use to achieve that? I prefer to use version 1.0, but it is not a requirement.

Comment: I have expanded option (c). If you want an XSLT 1.0 solution you will probably have to go with option (a), but I'm not going to expand that for you - I last used 1.0 in anger about 15 years ago and I have forgotten all the tricks to work around its limitations.